# Logic in jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, plugins

i found this plugin: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

My only question is, what happens in

```
search.php ?
```

Is there only a array in search.php?

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search.php simply echos json in the form of:

```
[{"label":"somelabelvalue","value":"somevalue"},{"label":"somelabelvalue","value":"somevalue"}]
```

or

```
["somelabelvalue","somelabelvalue"]
```

example:

```
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

Comment: but maximum is one array or?

Comment: Correct, one array of values. the values can be strings or objects.